# Efficient way to move large number of rows from one table to another new table using postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am using **PostgreSQL** database for live project. In which, I have one table with 8 columns.
This table contains millions of rows, so to make search faster from table, I want to delete and store old entries from this table to new another table.

To do so, I know one approach:

- first select some rows
- create new table
- store this rows in that table
- than delete from main table.

But it takes too much time and it is not efficient.

So I want to know what is the best possible approach to perform this in postgresql database?

Postgresql version: `9.4.2.`
Approx number of rows: 8000000
I want to move rows: 2000000

Comment: instead of moving the `larger older` volume of data, move the `smaller newer` volume of data to a new table. and just point to this new table, or rename the tables to do the switch in place.

Comment: Another option might be to tune the queries on the main table. But to be able to help you with that, you have not supplied enough information. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35837354/edit)  your question and add the missing information

Comment: You have a scaleability problem. Simple answer: don't search using Postgres. Export the whole thing into a text-based search engine ( eg Elasticsearch) and use that. You will be astounded at just how fast they are.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian . I will take look at elasticsearch. But still I want to know about possible solution to move data.

Comment: There is no generic best-possible approach.  What kind of down-time, if any, can you tolerate?  Will anyone be querying the old rows while you are trying to delete them?  Do they need to disappear from one table and reappear in another in an atomic manner? Do you have enough space to have two full copies of the data around simultaneously?

Comment: Why is renaming the table a risk?  What is it at risk of?  This restriction is going to rule out many of your best options.

Comment: ohk. i got your point. @jjanes . Thank you for your reply !

Answer (score 7):

You can use CTE (common table expressions) to move rows in a single SQL statement ([more in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)):

```
with delta as (
  delete from one_table where ...
  returning *
)
insert into another_table
select * from delta;
```

But think carefully whether you actually need it. Like a_horse_with_no_name said in the comment, tuning your queries might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample code for copying data between two table of same.
 Here i used different DB, one is my production DB and other is my testing DB

```
INSERT INTO "Table2"
select * from dblink('dbname=DB1 dbname=DB2 user=postgres password=root', 
'select "col1","Col2" from "Table1"') 
as t1(a character varying,b character varying);
```