# Copy postgres table to another schema using liquibase

Tags: database, postgresql, liquibase

I want to copy a set of tables from one schema to another schema on the same database. I use postgres v9 on Ubuntu and we use Liquibase for doing any changes to our database.

I am able to create new tables using code similar to below, but I need to create the new table as a `select * from another table`

```
<changeSet author="jDoe" id="1">
    <createTable tableName="abcproxy">
        <column name="errtime" type="datetime">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="errmsg" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="version" type="integer">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
```

I know we can do this via sql as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837354/efficient-way-to-move-large-number-of-rows-from-one-table-to-another-new-table-u), but I want to do it via Liquibase XML configurations. Also, it would be great if we can get the grants/privileges to be copied over using liquibase config.

I can try to move the tables as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910261/move-table-from-one-schema-to-another-schema) but as of now, my requirement is to *copy* and not *move* the tables.

Please let me know any suggestions to achieve the same. Thanks.

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: You can use <changeSet author="jDoe" id="1">
        <sql>select * from another table</sql>
    </changeSet>

Comment: Let me try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sql` tag inside your `changeSet`, e.g.:

```
<changeSet author="jDoe" id="1">
    <precondition onFail="MARK_RUN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="abcproxy" schemaName="newSchema"/>
        </not>
    </precondition>
    <sql>create table newSchema.abcproxy as select * from oldSchema.abcproxy</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Althow, there's an issue with this approach: this `changeSet` will copy all the data from your table in old schema, but not the keys.